# predict with different time step in LSTM using keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I am using keras to predict time series with LSTM and I realize that we can predict using datas that has not the same timestep than the ones we used to train. For example:

```
import numpy as np 
import keras.optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Activation,Dropout,TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import LSTM

Xtrain = np.random.rand(10,3,2) #Here timestep is 3
Ytrain = np.random.rand(10,1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_dim = Xtrain.shape[2],output_dim =10,return_sequences = False))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(1))

KerasOptimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=KerasOptimizer)
model.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain,nb_epoch = 1,batch_size = 1)

XBis = np.random.rand(10,4,2) #here timestep is 4
XTer = np.random.rand(10,2,2) #here timestep is 2

model.predict(Xtrain)
model.predict(XBis)
model.predict(XBis)
```

So my question is: why is that? If we train a model with `n` timesteps and we use data with `n+1` timestep for prediction maybe the model uses only the first `n` timesteps. But if we try to predict with `n-1` timestep, how is it working?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at how the `LSTM` layer is defined in your example, you will note that you are not telling specifically what is the size of the time dimension, only the number of features present at each time point (`input_dim`) and the number of desired output features (`output_dim`). Also, since you have `return_sequences=False` it will only output the result at the last time point, so the tensor yielded by the layer will always have the shape [batch size] x [output dim] (in this case, 10 x 10), discarding the time dimension.

So the size of the time dimension does not really affect to the "applicability" of the model; the layer will just go through all the available time steps and give you the last output.

Of course, that does not mean that the model will necessarily work *well* for any input. If all the examples in your training data have a time dimension of size `N` but the you try to predict using `N+1`, `N-1`, `100 * N` or whatever else, you may not have reliable results.

Comment: What if each instance has different timesteps?    
I have buy historical 7-days purchase, but each customer buys different quantity of items.